# How to prevent SD card from creating write delays during logging?

Tags: performance, arduino, sd-card, timing

I've been working on an Arduino (ATMega328p) prototype that has to log data during certain events. An LSM6DS33 sensor is used to generate 6 values (2 bytes each) at a sample rate of 104 Hz. This data needs to be logged for a period of 500-20000ms.

In my code, I generate an interrupt every 1/104 sec using Timer1. When this interrupt occurs, data is read from the sensor, calibrated and then written to an SD card. Normally, this is not an issue. Reading the data from the sensor takes ~3350us, calibrating ~5us and writing ~550us. This means a total cycle takes ~4000us, whereas 9615us is available.

In order to save power, I wish to lower the voltage to 3.3V. According to the atmel datasheet, this also means that the clock frequency should be lowered to 8MHz. Assuming everything will go twice as slow, a measurement cycle would still be possible because ~8000us < 9615us.

After some testing (still 5V@16MHz), however, it occured to me that every now and then, a write cycle would take ~1880us instead of ~550us. I am using the library SdFat to write and test SD cards (RawWrite example). The following results came in when I tested the card:

Start raw write of 100000 KB
Target rate: 100 KB/sec
Target time: 100 seconds
Min block write time: 1244 micros
Max block write time: 12324 micros
Avg block write time: 1247 micros

As seen, the average time to write is fairly consistent, but sometimes a peak duration of 10x average occurs! According to the writer of the library, this is because the SD card needs some erase cycles in between x amount of write cycles. This causes a write delay ([src:post#18&#22](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=98898.15)). This delay, however, pushes the time required for a cycle out of the available 9615us bracket, because the total measure cycle would be 10672us.

The data I am trying to write, is first put into a string using sprintf:

```
char buf[20] = "";
sprintf(buf,"%li\t%li\t%li\t%li\t%li\t%li",rawData[0],rawData[1],rawData[2],rawData[3],rawData[4],rawData[5]);
myLog.println(buf);
```

This writes the data to a txt file. But at my speed rate, only 21*104=2184 B/s would suffice. Lowering the speed of the RawWrite example to 6 KB/s, causes the SD card to write without getting an extended write delay. Yet my code still has them, even though less data is written.

My question is: how do I prevent this delay from occurring (if possible)? And if not possible, how can I work around it? It would help if I understood why exactly the delay occurs, because the interval is not always the same (every 10-15 writes).

Some additional info:
The sketch currently uses 69% of RAM (2kB) with variables. Creating two 512 byte buffers - like suggested in the same forum - is not possible for me.
Initially, I used two strings. Merging them into one, didn't affect the write speed with any significance.

Comment: The erase-delay is inherent to the SD-card. If it is full, you can expect even longer delays. Plus if the cells age, they take longer to eraseas well to write. While your question is too broad (we are not a consulting site), buffering might help, but as you say your RAM is at the edge, maybe Arduino (at least the ATmega-based) is not a suitable platform for your project. Finally: Arduino is **not** C. Don't spam tags.

Comment: If performance matters, why are you converting values into a string and writing text?  That takes more space and more time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: While I agree it is a bad idea to use `printf` etc. on such a small platform, it seems not to be the major problem. It will not avoid the SD-card stalls.

Comment: @Olaf But when the plan is to run with a margin like "~8000us < 9615us", I'd think every last microsecond matters.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The current values are most likely a lower estimate. Whne full or aged, erasure and programming of Flash blocks take much longer. There is just no guaranteed reaction time for these cards. The class only guarantees an average rate. SD-cards are just not real-time capable.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for the reply. While I do know the erase-delays are inherent, and having them occur sporadically is not a big issue, I am seeing them **up to 6 times per second** whereas the RawWrite example can write at 6 KB/s for 5 minutes and **never** get a write delay. But I agree, I posed the question too broad, should I rewrite it or delete and make a new one? (also, I thought Arduino was C.. sorry)

Comment: I don't see how this can be narrowed down, because it would require detailed inspection of the project, the architecture and the requirements. This is too broad for stack overflow, we are not a consulting site. I'd recommend to do this on your own, dig deeper into how SD cards work, possibly evaluate different techniques (e.g. SPI NOR-Flash) and review your architecture. Profiling the code would also be a good idea. One last thing: getting rid of `printf` and other bloat functions is always a good idea.

Comment: Two years later, I disagree with @toohonestforthissite in the suggestion that this question is too broad for this site. People working with SD libraries on embedded platforms are very familiar with this issue, there are well-known ways of working around it, and it is entirely reasonable to think that an answer would be forthcoming.  As it happens, a newer version of the SD library is available that resolves this particular problem, but it is not part of the Arduino distribution,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to work around the delay, but I experience a more stable and faster writing time, if I wrote to a binary file instead of a ".csv" or .txt" file.

The following link provide a fine script to write data as a binary struct to the SD card. (There are some small typo in his example, it is easily fixed)
https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/fast-efficient-data-storage-on-an-arduino/

This will not help you with the time variation, but it might minimize the writing time, and thus negleting the time issue.